# Fortify Security issue- Unreleased Resources: Database in java

Tags: java

I have scanned my project using fortify tool, in the generated fortify report I got Unreleased Resource: Database issue in the following code:

```
    PreparedStatement prepStatement = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    Connection connection1 = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
     try {
        connection = DBManager.getNewConnection(); //Line number=a 
        prepStatement = connection
                .prepareStatement("select P from table_name where parameter1 = ? and parameter2 = ?");
        prepStatement.setLong(1, parameter1 );
        prepStatement.setLong(2, parameter2 );
        resultSet = prepStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            var1= resultSet.getString("var");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to set the var field", e);
        throw new DatabaseRuntimeException(e,
                language.plainTxt("Unable to set the var field"));
    } finally {
        DBManager.close(prepStatement, resultSet);
        DBManager.close(connection);    //line number: b
    }
}//method end//  line number=c
```

Analysis trace shows:

- line a: connection refers to a database connection.
- line b: close(connection).
- line c: connection no longer refers to a database connection. //connection end scope : Database resource leaked.

Anybody let me know how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

What you're not taking into account here is a RuntimeException in the line "DBManager.close(prepStatement, resultSet);".
If that line fails with an exception the connection will never be closed.

That's probably why fortify flags it as a potential resource leak.